# How to prevent Emacs from converting JavaScript symbols to HTML code?

Tags: html, javascript

When I insert a portion of JavaScript code within an HTML file, Emacs convert some basic JS symbols to their HTML code. For example when I type `>`, Emacs convert it automatically to `&gt;` which this makes it impossible to code JS.

How to circumvent this issue?

**EDIT:**

Here is the content of my `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(ansi-color-faces-vector
   [default default default italic underline success warning error])
 '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (js2-mode green-is-the-new-black-theme))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "http://melpa-stable.milkbox.net/packages/"))


(require 'green-is-the-new-black-theme)

(setq column-number-mode t)     

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)

(setq sgml-quick-keys 'indent)

;; For JavaScript
(require 'js2-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.js\\'" . js2-mode))
;; Better imenu
(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'js2-imenu-extras-mode)
```

Comment: I can't replicate this in emacs 25.3 in `html-mode`.  I suspect you're using some mode or configuration which you haven't detailed in your question.  Please show how to replicate the problem, starting from `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you've configured:

```el
(setq sgml-quick-keys 'indent)
```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `sgml-quick-keys` tells us:

```
sgml-quick-keys is a variable defined in ‘sgml-mode.el’.

Documentation:
Use <, >, &, /, SPC and ‘sgml-specials’ keys "electrically" when non-nil.
This takes effect when first loading the ‘sgml-mode’ library.
```

As `html-mode` is derived from `sgml-mode`, this applies there as well.

Many people like http://web-mode.org/ for editing files which mix HTML/JS/CSS.