# Emacs forces me to write HTML tags instead of PHP code

Tags: html

When I edit a PHP file, and when to type for example `<?php` I get the cursor moved to the lower buffer suggesting me to write an HTML tag instead:

[image]
How to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for the same reason as https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/44076/454

For writing pure PHP I highly recommend using https://github.com/emacs-php/php-mode

If you're writing mixed HTML/PHP files, then http://web-mode.org/ may be a better option.